Spring Integration - Async Flow Switching to BoundedElastic
We have an IntegrationFlow that uses reactive via .async(true) and works great, except for switching to a boundedElatic thread.
Scenario is a high volume transaction flow with 1M+ messages being processed in a couple of hours from a Jms thread. Since the IntegrationFlow is switching to boundedElastic, the Jms thread is being released and it is consuming more messages than being processed (boundedElastic messages are pending with the boundedElastic thread), thereby resulting in OOM error.
Below is a sample to see the IntegrationFlow switching to boundedElastic though NO mention of .subscribeOn() done on application side
https://github.com/syedyusufh/thread-switching.git
Logs:
[2m2024-10-07T20:05:44.210+04:00[0;39m [32m INFO[thread-switching] [   scheduling-1][0;39m [2m[670406d8ea2283eb5c63e8899ab1690f-b92b2eda2e231d22] [0;39m[36mo.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m ************ Flow started *****************
[2m2024-10-07T20:05:44.320+04:00[0;39m [32m INFO[thread-switching] [   scheduling-1][0;39m [2m[670406d8ea2283eb5c63e8899ab1690f-fd5115e02e6cb1ee] [0;39m[36mc.i.sample.handler.MockDBHandler        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m DB call is successful
[2m2024-10-07T20:05:44.336+04:00[0;39m [32m INFO[thread-switching] [oundedElastic-1][0;39m [2m[670406d8ea2283eb5c63e8899ab1690f-a28d62414e24fe2d] [0;39m[36mc.i.sample.handler.MockJmsHandler       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m JMS call is successful


Not clear what is your question. You are switching to an async handling, therefore it is expected that producing thread is free to produce more. It does not matter if it reactive on the handler side or not, the JMS is not reactive, therefore setting free its thread leads to the mentioned behavior. There is a customizeMonoReply() to apply alongside with that async(true). However, I'm not sure if you need that async(true) at all...

Please see my edit, can the thread switch on the last line (oundedElastic-1) controlled? Switching to boundedElastic should happen only if the call is made for subscribeOn(Schedulers.boudnedElastic()). Please correct me if Im wrong

That happens in the AbstractMessageProducingHandler when we process that reply Mono and we do that explicitly via .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).

Something like this [thread-switching] [   scheduling-1] [67042b8b34b14b638139e5eabfa4f262-0081506a76829d82] c.i.sample.handler.MockJmsHandler        : JMS call is successful will be OK with you by default? Then you can modify that behavior with the mentioned customizeMonoReply().

Fixed via: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9538
